# Address in autocomplete results

Tags: here-api, autosuggest, here-maps-rest, heremaps

When I do an autosuggest request in the address response I only receive the label. The address object is not filled.

This is my request: https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=48.8578817,2.2791249999999934&limit=5&q=stj&apikey=xxxx

I receive this:

```
            "title": "Top Services (Stj)",
            "id": "here:pds:place:250u09wj-afceace0a11b49bca950ea22d0f8e452",
            "resultType": "place",
            "address": {
                "label": "********"
            },
```

I will need to receive the formatted address without the name

How can I fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to reproduce your query and it works for us, please see the following code.

Please review the documentation page for detailed information on autosuggest

Documentation link :

https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=48.8578817,2.2791249999999934&limit=5&q=stj&apikey=XXXX.

**Query Result:**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "Top Services (Stj)",
      "id": "here:pds:place:250u09wj-afceace0a11b49bca950ea22d0f8e452",
      "resultType": "place",
      "address": {
        "label": "Top Services, 61 Rue du Faubourg Saint-Denis, 75010 Paris, France"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 48.8721,
        "lng": 2.35384
      },
      "access": [
        {
          "lat": 48.87208,
          "lng": 2.35392
        }
      ],
      "distance": 5690,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "700-7200-0254",
          "name": "Construction",
          "primary": true
        },
        {
          "id": "700-7200-0264",
          "name": "Services de conseil et de gestion"
        },
        {
          "id": "700-7200-0277",
          "name": "Entrepreneur de second œuvre"
        }
      ],
      "highlights": {
        "title": [
          {
            "start": 14,
            "end": 17
          }
        ],
        "address": {
          "label": [
            
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "La Clinique du Scooter d'Occasion (Stj 2 Roues)",
      "id": "here:pds:place:250u09tv-591de1b090c54199b11154a72f462c0d",
      "resultType": "place",
      "address": {
        "label": "La Clinique du Scooter d'Occasion, 148 Boulevard du Montparnasse, 75014 Paris, France"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 48.84039,
        "lng": 2.33383
      },
      "access": [
        {
          "lat": 48.84052,
          "lng": 2.33393
        }
      ],
      "distance": 4451,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "400-4200-0241",
          "name": "Services logistiques",
          "primary": true
        }
      ],
      "highlights": {
        "title": [
          {
            "start": 35,
            "end": 38
          }
        ],
        "address": {
          "label": [
            
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Stjohn's",
      "id": "here:pds:place:2501r4ve-43f913ba8f9b0e7046aaee61bcfe8b9b",
      "resultType": "place",
      "address": {
        "label": "Stjohn's, 11 Rue Edmond Valentin, 75007 Paris, France"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 48.85961,
        "lng": 2.30159
      },
      "access": [
        {
          "lat": 48.85968,
          "lng": 2.30157
        }
      ],
      "distance": 1655,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "700-7400-0141",
          "name": "Services aux entreprises",
          "primary": true
        },
        {
          "id": "700-7200-0252",
          "name": "Publicité, marketing, communication et études de marché"
        }
      ],
      "highlights": {
        "title": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "end": 3
          }
        ],
        "address": {
          "label": [
            {
              "start": 0,
              "end": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Stjohn S",
      "id": "here:pds:place:250u09tv-0f38e06dd8634ab4a0d931dad94de24c",
      "resultType": "place",
      "address": {
        "label": "Stjohn S, 4 Rue des Petits-Pères, 75002 Paris, France"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 48.86601,
        "lng": 2.34027
      },
      "access": [
        {
          "lat": 48.8662,
          "lng": 2.34023
        }
      ],
      "distance": 4564,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "700-7200-0252",
          "name": "Publicité, marketing, communication et études de marché",
          "primary": true
        },
        {
          "id": "700-7200-0271",
          "name": "Services financiers et d'assurance"
        }
      ],
      "highlights": {
        "title": [
          {
            "start": 0,
            "end": 3
          }
        ],
        "address": {
          "label": [
            {
              "start": 0,
              "end": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Espace St-Jo'",
      "id": "here:pds:place:250u09te-220742c64e4a40a48b8772987e7f987c",
      "resultType": "place",
      "address": {
        "label": "Espace St-Jo', 54 Rue du Moulin de Pierres, 92140 Clamart, France"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 48.80865,
        "lng": 2.26594
      },
      "access": [
        {
          "lat": 48.8087,
          "lng": 2.2659
        }
      ],
      "distance": 5558,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "200-2200-0000",
          "name": "Théâtre, musique et culture",
          "primary": true
        },
        {
          "id": "200-2000-0015",
          "name": "Salle de spectacle/concert"
        },
        {
          "id": "550-5520-0000",
          "name": "Aire de loisirs"
        }
      ],
      "references": [
        {
          "supplier": {
            "id": "yelp"
          },
          "id": "xJtl5krT8OZ3QYXtMl6Leg"
        }
      ],
      "highlights": {
        "title": [
          {
            "start": 7,
            "end": 12
          }
        ],
        "address": {
          "label": [
            {
              "start": 7,
              "end": 12
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "queryTerms": [
    
  ]
}
```